# JavaFx 2 draw arrows

Tags: charts, line, javafx-2

This code plots a simple XYLine Chart

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class XyChart extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
   stage.setTitle("Line plot");

   final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
   final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 21,0.1);

   yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
   yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
   yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);

   yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
        @Override
    public String toString(Number object){
            String label;
            label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            return label;
    }
});
final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

   lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
   lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
   lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

   XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 2.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(lineChart);          
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);       

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}   
}
```

I would like to draw arrows on the chart by left mouse click pressed and moved, such as this example

[image]

How to do this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add mouse handlers to the border pane and draw the arrow when the mouse moves.
There might be better ways, but this is what I came up with:

Add mouse handler to your border pane:

```
MouseHandler mh = new MouseHandler( pane );
pane.setOnMouseClicked( mh );
pane.setOnMouseMoved( mh );
```

The handler class could be as follows:

```
class MouseHandler implements EventHandler< MouseEvent > {
    private boolean gotFirst    = false;
    private Line    line, head1, head2;
    private Pane    pane;
    private double  x1, y1, x2, y2;
    double          phi         = Math.toRadians( 40 );
    double          barb        = 20;

    public MouseHandler( Pane pane ) {
        this.pane = pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
        if( event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED ) {
            if( !gotFirst ) {
                x1 = x2 = event.getX();
                y1 = y2 = event.getY();
                line = new Line( x1, y1, x2, y2 );
                head1 = new Line( x2, y2, x2, y2 );
                head2 = new Line( x2, y2, x2, y2 );
                pane.getChildren().add( line );
                pane.getChildren().add( head1 );
                pane.getChildren().add( head2 );
                gotFirst = true;
            } else {
                line = null;
                gotFirst = false;
            }
        } else {
            if( line != null ) {
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();
                // update line
                line.setEndX( x2 );
                line.setEndY( y2 );
                // draw head
                // http://www.coderanch.com/t/340443/GUI/java/Draw-arrow-head-end-line
                double dx = x2 - x1;
                double dy = y2 - y1;
                double theta = Math.atan2( dy, dx );
                double x, y, rho = theta + phi;

                x = x2 - barb * Math.cos( rho );
                y = y2 - barb * Math.sin( rho );
                head1.setStartX( x2 );
                head1.setStartY( y2 );
                head1.setEndX( x );
                head1.setEndY( y );
                rho = theta - phi;
                x = x2 - barb * Math.cos( rho );
                y = y2 - barb * Math.sin( rho );
                head2.setStartX( x2 );
                head2.setStartY( y2 );
                head2.setEndX( x );
                head2.setEndY( y );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Bhupendra,
your solution is really good. One last question: how to delete arrows one by one? I mean, select an arrow then delete by, for example, right mouse click.
Thank you very much

Comment: This what you could do:
1. Add all lines to a list.
2. Add mouse handler to each line.
3. In the mouse handler, get the source (Line)
4. Remove the line from the list.
Experiment with it, if your still having trouble, i'll code when i get home.

Comment: Thanks Bhupendra, your help really appreciated! I wait for your code when possibile.